# I'm having trouble with Pod installation on Mac M2 problem

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, apple-silicon, pod-install

I have problem with pods to install using MacBook air with M2 chip

I tried this code

```
pod install
```

also I tried

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

I got an error

```
Cloning into '/var/folders/l8/bl4m0txx6vjcxbg6ffkg6kzr0000gn/T/d20230815-2276-e5r3rz'...
         error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
         error: 7302 bytes of body are still expected
         fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
         fatal: early EOF
         fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Please add the error/issue you are facing in installing pod.